# Rubymotion: Rake fails

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, rubymotion

I am using ruby 1.9.3-p484, Xcode 5.1, and OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and I get the following error when running `rake` with RubyMotion.

```
$ rake
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.1-Development
     Build vendor/Pods/NewRelicAgent/NewRelic_iOS_Agent_3.252/NewRelicAgent.framework
      Link ./build/iPhoneSimulator-7.1-Development/Themes.app/Themes
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NewRelicAgent(NewRelicInternalUtils.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      -[NRHarvesterConnection createPostWithURI:message:] in NewRelicAgent(NRHarvesterConnection.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      -[NRHarvesterConnection createPostWithURI:message:] in NewRelicAgent(NRHarvesterConnection.o)
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      -[NRHarvesterConnection createPostWithURI:message:] in NewRelicAgent(NRHarvesterConnection.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer...]

Tasks: TOP => build:simulator
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Try installing it using the download from New Relics site. 
http://newrelic.com/ios-app-optimization Make sure you add the frameworks they need as well. Hopefully that will get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
rake clean
```

Or

Open XCode goto Preferences > Downloads > Components and Install 5.1 Stimulator if its not installed. Then in your Rakefile set

```
app.sdk_version = "5.1"
```